# using a formula to compute a column value in sql

Tags: sql

Hi i have this 2 table:

[image]

[image]

I want to compute med_pr value and update it with the result from this formula:

> (table1.med/table2.total) * (39/69)

```
where table1.number = table2.number
```

How should i do this? thanks for your replays.
Sorry im newbies in sql.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` clauses can have `JOIN`s.

```
UPDATE table1
SET med_pr = ((table1.med / table2.total) * (39 / 69))
FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.number = table2.number
```

You'll probably want to run this as a `SELECT` first, of course, as is the SOP of doing `UPDATE`s, but I believe it should give the result you're looking for.

Comment: it put 0 in all of med_pr fields why? :(

Comment: what do you think is the cause of this? datatype of the column 'med_pr' is float and table1.med & table2.total are int

Comment: i find out that when i remove this part '* (39 / 69)' from your query it gives the correct answer but when add it, it just return 0!